# JMX data as a JSON

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I want to monitor Spring beans using JMX, but it's quite painful to make it work with composite data. So I decided to map returned values to JSON text strings. But is it a common solution? Is it conceptually right? What can go wrong?

Comment: why close??????

Comment: may be you are looking for spring boot admin.. http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/, if you are using spring boot

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/features/overview.html)

> Jolokia is an agent based approach for remote JMX access. It is an alternative to standard JSR 160 connectors. The communication between client and agent goes over HTTP (either GET or POST), **where the request and response payload is represented in JSON**.

For java code implementing JMX as JSON see [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans)

> This is effectively the missing connector between speaking to a JVM via JMX on one end and whatever logging / monitoring / graphing package that you can dream up on the other end.
>
> jmxtrans is very powerful tool which uses easily generated JSON (or YAML) based configuration files and then outputs the data in whatever format you desire.